# How to specify a database other than "default" for dj-stripe in a Django app?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a Django app with three databases and am trying to synchronize each with dj-stripe, using the command line with the command "./manage.py djstripe_sync_models"? My settings.py includes:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_NAME", default="default"),
        "USER": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_USER", default="postgres"),
        "PASSWORD": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_PASSWORD", default="***"),
        "HOST": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_HOST", default="localhost"),
        "PORT": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_PORT", default="5432"),
    },
    "database_2": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_NAME2"),
        "USER": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_HOST", default="localhost"),
        "PORT": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_PORT", default="5432"),
    },
    "database_3": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_NAME3"),
        "USER": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_HOST", default="localhost"),
        "PORT": env("DJANGO_DATABASE_PORT", default="5432"),
    },
}
```

Can I specify which database to populate for dj-stripe? The  "./manage.py djstripe_sync_models"? resorts to the "default" database only. So far the only thing that has worked is to comment out two of the databases and temporarily name each "default".

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be something you would need to implement in a custom [Django Database Router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing)

Since `dj-stripe` is just a 3rd party app, you would need to configure a router that tells the Django DB engine which database to use based on the app label.